# Using a DataTemplate for a MenuItem causes extra space on the left side to appear?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

Whenever I attach a DataTemplate to a MenuItem, each generated menu item gets an extra space on the left side. This extra space looks as wide as the space reserved for the check, which I use. Building a menu manually without a DataTemplate doesn't add this extra space. As an extra wrinkle, if I click on this extra space the menu item goes away but no click event is generated. I don't know why it's adding this extra space. Any ideas?

my xaml code couldn't be more simpler:

Menu with the described extra spaces:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Enemies" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableEnemyClasses}">
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding}">
                </MenuItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Menu without extra spaces:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Utilities" >
        <MenuItem Header="Enemy01"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Enemy02"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Enemy03"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: more info: https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon/issues/188

Comment: and see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965464/wpf-menuitem-icon-in-the-wrong-place-when-using-data-template?rq=1

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's because the visual tree produced by your `DataTemplate` will be wrapped in a container - in this case, a `MenuItem`. Therefore, you actually have a `MenuItem` within a `MenuItem`, which explains the extra space and the lack of interactivity. There's no need to include the `MenuItem` in your `ItemTemplate`.

Your example might instead be written as:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Enemies" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableEnemyClasses}">
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Or, perhaps more succinctly:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Enemies" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableEnemyClasses}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
                            <Binding .../>
                            <Binding .../>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had another question: With an ItemContainerStyle, how would I bind the MenuItem's IsChecked property to a multibinding?

Comment: No problem. That should probably be a separate question, but I updated my answer to show you how.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thanks Kent!

Comment: Excellent response, I'm tackling something similar to the original question. In view of your answer, is a Converter the only way of setting the IsChecked to say true only for some children, or is there another way (Triggers for instance) ? Thank you ! I've posted a question for this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305439/how-to-set-a-menuitems-ischecked-property-for-a-child-of-type-enum-via-xaml)

Comment: What will YourConverter actually convert?

Comment: second option seems like the better one as most of the reason your likely to want to put a menu item in the menu item is that you want to change the menu item properties eg Command or IsChecked property, though a gramma nazi might dispute your use of the word succinctly

Comment: Had same issue with RibbonMenuItem and this solution also applies to that.