# WPF: MenuItem icon in the wrong place when using data template

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I have the following code:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding SomethingMenuItems}" Header="Something"/>
</Menu>
```

Where MenuItems is a collection of objects of type SomethingMenuItem.

I also have:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SomethingMenuItem}">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding OrderTypeName}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="{Binding IconName}"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'd expect to get (I get something like this when I hardcode the menu items):

[image]

What I get instead is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, sthotakura's answer set me on the right track, but the code he posted didn't quite work because the style got applied to the parent menuitem as well.

In case someone else has a similar problem and stumbles on this question, here's the code that works:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding SomethingMenuItems}" 
          Header="Something">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" >
            <Style.Resources>
                <Image Source="{Binding IconPath}" x:Key="IconImage" x:Shared="False"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource IconImage}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `ItemContainerStyle` instead of `DataTemplate`. You have to style the container of the data item than just providing a template for data item.

With your `DataTemplate`, you basically displaying another nested MenuItem as content for each MenuItem generated for your Menu *Something*, and your inner MenuItem has the image in the correct place. I am attaching VisualTree from Snoop here for your reference.

[image: Nested MenuItems]

Below is the Style for the container of the data item (in this case a `MenuItem`):

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding SomethingMenuItems}" 
          Header="Something">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Image Source="{Binding IconPath}" x:Key="IconImage" x:Shared="False"/>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" >
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource IconImage}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

You can see no nested MenuItems when you apply the above style, have added image here
[image: No Nested MenuItems]

With the above style applied, this is how the Menu looks:

[image: Menu after Container Style]

Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) MSDN page to know more about `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: This almost works, but not quite. The problem is that the style defined there applies to "Something" as well as the rest of the child elements. As you can see in your own image, even though there are no image associated with "Something", there is still a space to the left there reserved for the image. If you remove the style, you'll see "Something" move to the left. If you look at your output, you'll also see binding errors due to WPF trying to bind on "IconPath" of the parent object (which is bad... imagine if the parent also had an IconPath property used for something completely different!"

Comment: Actually, I just realised that you mentioned ItemContainerStyle, but didn't actually use it in your code. ItemContainerStyle does work correctly, your code doesn't. So yeah, when I adapted your code to use ItemContainerStyle, it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: I basically took a shortcut to have the ItemContainerStyle defined implicitly. But yeah, if you have already got it working, post it and mark that as answer, so it will be useful for someone else.