# Getting selected menuitem when it is dynamically created

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I've got a ContextMenu that looks like this:

```
<ContextMenu StaysOpen="False" Width="150" x:Name="HistoryContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding HistorySetCurrent}" Header="Set _Current (C)"/>
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding HistorySetReference}" Header="Set _Reference (R)" />
    <MenuItem  Header="Add to Group" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Groups, Path=ChartGroups}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HistoryGroupContextClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

I'm using MVVM so I'm binding to a method to handle the PreviewMouseUp  event (I have tried other events too). I get a list in my submenu as wanted, but when I click on one of them, the eventargs I get contain all the menu items in the list, not just the one I selected, with no incdication of the one chosen. 
How do I find the selected menuitem? I've tried doing this with code behind, but the same problem occurs with that method too.

Comment: Did you try putting the trigger in the MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle (int Style resources)? So it applies to all sub items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `ItemContainerStyle` to manage the `Commands` on the generated `MenuItems`.

Have a look at Kent's answer to this question which shows you how to setup the style: [Using a DataTemplate for a MenuItem causes extra space on the left side to appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312895/using-a-datatemplate-for-a-menuitem-causes-extra-space-on-the-left-side-to-appea)

You would need to add the binding for the `Command` and the individual item as the `CommandParameter` in order to have context for the `Command` to run against.

Comment: I've added the following to replace the old command binding:

<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.HistoryGroupContextClickCommand}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" />
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>

but the commandparameter is still getting the parent, not the submenu

Comment: Surely you'd want the data item that the `MenuItem` represents? In which case set `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`?

Comment: Dammit, I got so wrapped up in the Menuitem side of things, I completely forgot about that... that does work...!