# Selective styling of MenuItems in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I have a `MenuItem` with several dynamic lists under headers. I want to style the items that come from the `CollectionContainer` items but not the  headers that are already of type `MenuItem`. I had previously been doing this by using a `DataTemplate`, but ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312895/using-a-datatemplate-for-a-menuitem-causes-extra-space-on-the-left-side-to-appea).

```
<MenuItem Header="Test">
    <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <MenuItem Header="List A" IsEnabled="False" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListACollectionViewSource}}" />
            <MenuItem Header="List B" IsEnabled="False" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListBCollectionViewSource}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
</MenuItem>
```

How can I style only those specific lists?

Comment: What do you mean style?  Do you mean that you want to apply a specific style to those elements?

Comment: Yes I want to have those items headers and IsChecked and several other things set based on the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to set a default style for MenuItems, which would then be used by the generated items.  Then, for the non-generated items, you can then explicitly  set the style to another style.

```
<!-- this will be the style of each generated MenuItem -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text, StringFormat=Example {0}}" />
  <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
  <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource TheImage}" />
</Style>
```

It becomes a bit verbose, but it allows a mix of dynamic and non-dynamic items:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
  <Menu.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Menu.ItemTemplate>
  <Menu.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <MenuItem Header="123" Style="{StaticResource NormalMenuItem}">
        <MenuItem Header="Beta1" Style="{StaticResource NormalMenuItem}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Beta2"  Style="{StaticResource NormalMenuItem}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Beta3"  Style="{StaticResource NormalMenuItem}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="Close" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=Window}" />
      </MenuItem>
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
  </Menu.ItemsSource>
</Menu>
```

Comment: My solution for the same problem was to specify `Tag="¤"` on the `MenuItem`s not in the collection, and then in `ItemContainerStyle` I specify a trigger on `Tag` to be equal to `{x:Null}` before applying the style. This makes it better in the sense that you are not altering the `MenuItem` *outside* of the `MenuItem` with the `CompsiteCollection`.  
Now what I'm looking for is to invert the `Tag` value to be set on the `MenuItem`s generated from the source.